# Copy cells in column M that start with "xx" and paste them into another sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to make a button that will find all cells in column H starting with rm and copy them from one sheet to another.

[sheet2 column M](https://i.stack.imgur.com/77wQV.png)
would go to
[sheet 1 column A](https://i.stack.imgur.com/axY1i.png)

```
Dim i As Variant
Dim rng As Range

Set x = Range("m" & i)

If Left(rng.Value, 2) = "rm" Then
For Each i In x
Worksheets("scope sheet").Range("A5").Value = Range(i)
Next i
End If
```

this gives an error "method 'range' of Object '_global' failed."

if i add a `With` statement i get "subscript out of range."

does anyone know a work around.

Comment: You are currently only extracting the first character from the string. You need to use `If Left(rng.Value, 2) = "rm"`

Comment: Your loop needs some work. What range are you trying to loop through? 2nd row to last used row?

Comment: corrected same errors and yes first row to last row but to only extract the specific cell not the whole row

Comment: please leave your question as is. Updating issues as we try to answer them changes the question we are trying to answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `Left(Range, 2)` and make some changes to your loop structure. The code is currently looping from the **second row** down to the last used row (**lr**)

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2") '<-- UPDATE SHEET
Dim i As Long, LR As Long

LR = ws.Range("M" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 2 To LR
    If Left(ws.Range("M" & i), 2) = "rm" Then
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & i).Value = ws.Range("M" & i).Value
    End If
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: This still returns "subscript out of range"

Comment: Did you update the sheet names in code accordingly? My code is looking for **Sheet1** and **Sheet2**

Comment: update sheets to correct name and it now works thank you